# preg_replace doubt

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What I'm doing wrong ?

```
echo preg_replace('#\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\d{2}#', '$1.$2.$3-$4', '12345678901');
```

Output would be this: **123.456.789-01**. Isn't formating the string!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('#(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})#', '$1.$2.$3-$4', '12345678901');
```

is correct, because dollar sign + integer refers to content in () brackets (grouping)

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d13f5/2)

Comment: Better phrasing would be to say that the OP is lacking any capture groups in the regex, so the capture variables are empty.

Answer (score 2):

You have not grouped correctly (missing brackets):

```
echo preg_replace('#(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})#', '$1.$2.$3-$4', '12345678901');
```

Comment: Damn, what a fool question I've asked. Thank you all.